# htaccess, mod_rewrite, remove part from URL

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, directory, public-folders

I want to access `domain.com/api/(.*)` instead of `domain.com/public/api/(.*)`

**Directory structure:**

```
domain.com
__folder1
__folder2
__public
____api
______.htaccess2
____afolder1
____afolder2
____index.html
__folder3
__file1
__file2
__.htaccess1
```

**.htaccess1**

```
RewriteEngine on
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV    production

RewriteRule ^$ /public/ [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
```

**.htaccess2**

```
RewriteEngine on
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV    production

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

I tried different combinations and I came to this simplest one.
I tried Alias, put the api folder on root directory, etc.

To mention that the index.html from public folder is loaded first at domain.com, public folder is document root.

Comment: Try to raise your mod_rewrite Loglevel. This is achieved differently for Apache 2.2 and 2.4: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging